# Cut and paste without range

Tags: excel, vba

So i need to cut and replace some specific cells, but i cant cut the second part because i dont want to specify the range cells since im going to repeat this a couple of times.

This is for a VBA in excell

```
Sub Recc()
ActiveWindow.Activate

    'This is the only one i want to specify
    ActiveSheet.Range("A175:C203").Select
    Range("A175:C203").Cut
    Range("A175:C203").Offset(-34, 9).Select
    ActiveSheet.paste
    'I dont want to specify range here since the selection is already made
    ActiveCell.Offset(34, -6).Select
    ActiveCell.Resize(29, 8).Select

    'i cant cut :(
    ActiveSheet.Cut

End Sub
```

I want the selection cut.

Comment: You can work with the `Selection` directly, e.g., `Selection.Cut` But this is generally frowned upon, as a rule `Selection` should really only be used as initial user input, you shouldn't be writing code that simulates mouse-clicks, keystrokes, etc., because there are vastly more efficient ways to do this using the API/object model.